# How do connect a Google Sheet for the purpose of mapping external-facing labels to my existing data sets in Looker Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, visualization, analytics, looker-studio

I am struggling to be able to create visualisations in Google Looker Studio using the naming convention outlined in my *Intended Mapping Table* (Column A + B) .

I am faced with a scenario where my *Existing Data Set* contains the values I want to visualise (Column B) but uses internal-facing names for products and services (Column A). These internal names are often using slightly different wording or different grammer (one line item may have capitals and spaces and the next does not even through they are referring to the same service).

Intended Mapping Table

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Product Family 1 | internal 1 | Internal1 |
| Product 2 | Product Family 1 | internal 2 | Internal2 |

Existing Data Set

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| internal 1 | 100 |
| internal 2 | 200 |
| Internal1 | 50 |
| Internal2 | 50 |

Intended Output

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Product Family 1 | 150 |
| Product 2 | Product Family 1 | 250 |

All data is imported to Looker Studio using Google Sheets. The only purpose the *Intended Mapping Table* serves is to be a matrix to translate all other data sources into external facing. I want to be able to use this matrix as the Join Condition between other data sets where there isn't already a clear relationship.

I have attempted to setup several data blends, trying all 5 join operations.

I have also tried to setup these blends using two and three tables:

Intended Mapping Table (Column C, Column D) > Existing Data Set (Column A, Column A)

or

Existing Data Set (Column A) > Intended Mapping Table (Column C, Column D) < Existing Data Set (Column A)

The outcomes have either been:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Product Family 1 | 100 |
| Product 2 | Product Family 1 | 200 |

OR

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Product Family 1 | null |
| Product 2 | Product Family 1 | null |